# DateEdit value change

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I would like to add  minute (which is entered from a calcEdit) to starting date then it wil be set as end date.
Also when I enter the end date the subtract of start time will be set as minute .

I tried dateEdit's EditValueChanged ,Validating events and I tried both for calcedit but got wrong values.

I use g mask for dateEdits

Please help me thank you.

Here are my codes :

```
   `private void calcEditMinute_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            dtBitisZamani = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEditBas.EditValue).AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(calcEditMinute.Text));
            dateEditBit.EditValue = dtBitisZamani;




        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

    }

  private void dateEditBit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        TimeSpan span = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEditBit.EditValue).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(dateEditBas.EditValue));
        calcEditMinute.Text = string.Format(" {0} ",
span.Minutes); span.TotalMinutes.ToString();


    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   private void calcEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        dateEditEnd.DateTime = dateEditStart.DateTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(calcEdit1.Value));
    }

    private void dateEditEnd_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateEditStart.DateTime = dateEditEnd.DateTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(calcEdit1.Value) * -1);
    }
```